# Translating assembly

Tags: c, assembly

So I'm learning how to convert the assembly into readable C code. The assembly is as follows...

```
Consider the compiler places the C variables: a at -4(%rbp), b at -8(%rbp), and c at -12(rbp). 


file "main.c"
.text
.globl main
.type main, @function
main:
endbr64
pushq %rbp
movq %rsp, %rbp
movl $10, -12(%rbp)
movl $20, -4(%rbp)
movl $1, -8(%rbp)
.L4:
cmpl $1, -12(%rbp)
je .L7
movl -8(%rbp), %eax
imull -12(%rbp), %eax
movl %eax, -8(%rbp)
subl $1, -12(%rbp)
jmp .L4
.L7:
nop
movl -4(%rbp), %eax
imull -8(%rbp), %eax
movl %eax, -4(%rbp)
movl $0, %eax
popq %rbp
ret
```

This is what I have so far.

```
int c = 10; 
int a = 20; 
int b = 1; 


for(c = 10; c > 1; c--)
{
int x = b; 
x = c * x; 
b = x; 
}
```

Not completely sure how correct that is. The part that confuses me the most is the appearance (from what seems like out of nowhere) of eax. When eax appears, should I just assume that it is some other random variable? (hence the integer x I introduced)

Comment: IMO this kind of exercises is a complete waste of time. First of all this kind of code will be only generated without any optimisations. No one will write this kind of code in assembler and C code is almost always compiled with at least some optimizations enabled.

Comment: You could just write `int main() { return 0; }`.  It has the same observable side-effects (in terms of the calling convention) as this asm, which just messes around with some space on the stack which is deallocated when it returns.